# Best practice for synchronizing an object between threads

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

I basically have an object which stores the 3D location of an item with additional attributes like speed. The location gets calculated every 100 ms by a separate thread. Another thread accesses theses attributes and modifies some of them.

#### Simulation Thread

```java
// ...
double z = location.getZ();
// calculate new position
location.setZ(z);
// ...
```

#### Other Thread

```java
// ...
while(location.getZ() > 10); // Some busy waiting for demonstration
location.setSpeed(10);
// ...
```

My first idea was to simply use `volatile` for every attribute but as far as I understand every operation on a volatile attribute must be atomic. As both threads are allowed to change certain attributes (like speed) at some circumstances this doesn't seem to be working.

My next idea was to use java's `synchronized` keyword and synchronize every getter and setter end the entire simulation cycle.

```java
// Location.java
public synchronized double getZ() { /* ... */ }

// Simulation loop
synchronized(location) {
    // calculations are done here
}
```

Now I was wondering wherever this is the right approach or if there is a better one.

Is it okay to call `getZ()` inside the `synchronized` block or does this result inside  do I need a separate lock?

Comment: 1. An architecture when 2 different threads mutate one single shared structure according to some rule seems to be a bit odd and dangerous. You may get both data races and race conditions. I'd recommend thinking twice and, maybe, redesign this solution using some queues, for example. 2. But if you insist... :) I'd add a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock into the location structure and use the lock for consistent reading and writing instead of the synchronized block. Acquire the lock, read/modify required fields, and release the lock.

Comment: Why does a location have a “speed” property? I agree with Anatoly G; synchronization can only solve the lowlevel issues, it doesn’t fix the logical problems of your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach with synchronized looks correct. Volatile makes sure there is happens-before relationship with next read of the same variable. But it doesn't establish atomicity.

You can use synchronize keyword to make sure that both happens-before & atomicity work properly. Just make sure you are locking on the same monitor object in both getter & setter methods.

Getter method also needs synchronization. Otherwise getter method can read the variable value from local CPU cache & not from main memory as happens-before property is not established. So some other thread might have updated the value in main memory using a synchronized setter, but getter is still reading the stale cached value from CPU cache.

Comment: Couldn't have said that better! Very good

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So if I call a getter or setter of `Location` (method with `synchronized` keyword) inside the `synchronized` block of the simulation threat this does not result in a deadlock as I acquire a lock for the same object twice?

Comment: Java lock is reentrant for the same thread. That means if a thread has acquired a monitor object once & then again it tries to acquire a lock on the same monitor object, it will work seamlessly. I think in your case, you have a synchronized block on "location" object. And your getter is on "this" object which is also a location object instance. If both objects are referring to the single object instance, you shouldn't have any problem. It will work as per the reentrant lock scenario.

Comment: On X86 and ARM the caches are always coherent. So you can't read a stale value.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to just replace the whole object when you update it.

E.g.

```
class State{
    final int x,y;
    ... constructor + getters
}

volatile State state;

public void update(int x, int y){
    this.state = new State(x,y);
}

public void useState(){
    State s = state;
    print(s.x+" "+s.y);
}
```

The big advantage is that you can always return a consistent object; not an object that has some in between state. It makes concurrency a lot easier because the state object is immutable.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! As far as I understand the threat would get notified when the object reference changes, correct? Is where any difference in performance between these two approaches?

Comment: If you write to a volatile, another thread will see the change. I would be more concerned about the spinning in your system.

Comment: With spinning you mean the polling of the other thread (`while(location.getZ() > 10);`) right?

Comment: Correct. Probably you want to make use of some kind of synchronization primitive to prevent keeping the CPU busy.

Comment: When I use the volatile approach, how can I prevent a race condition or does a change of the second thread has any effect at all? Does the simulation thread ever sees the change?

Comment: There is a difference between a race condition and a data race. A volatile will help to prevent the data race; it will not help to prevent a race condition. So with a volatile there is a happens before edge between the write of the field and the read of the field (so you visibility is guaranteed).